# "|" Operator inside c# string - how to escape it?

Tags: c#, string, escaping

I have following string - which is an argument to execute an exe.

But I am getting error - "Operator "|" can not be applied to operand of type string and string.

Ho do I escape my "|" ? I tried \, didnt work :(

```
string.Format(
                        @"-S -E -M -m -e ascii -i {0}.dat -T db1.dbo.table1 -R {1}.reject -t "|" -r \r\n -rt value -rv 1000 -W  -fh 0", 
                        saveFilePath + a,
                        saveFilePath + b);
```

Comment: Why don't you use "string \|" instead of @""|"" ?

Comment: It is not `|` that needs escaping, it is the double quotes. Use double double quotes.

Comment: In that case do I need to keep "@" at the beginning?

Comment: I tried that without @ - but it was giving me error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `@"..."` literal, to have a `"` character, you must use two of them. So:

```
string.Format(
    @"-S -E -M -m -e ascii -i {0}.dat -T db1.dbo.table1 -R {1}.reject -t ""|"" -r \r\n -rt value -rv 1000 -W  -fh 0", 
// note -----------------------------------------------------------------^^-^^
    saveFilePath + a,
    saveFilePath + b);
```

**However**, if you wanted those `\r` and `\n` to be a carriage return and a newline, you can't use a `@"..."` string literal because backslash isn't special in them (that's the whole point of them). So if that's the case:

```
    string.Format(
        "-S -E -M -m -e ascii -i {0}.dat -T db1.dbo.table1 -R {1}.reject -t \"|\" -r \r\n -rt value -rv 1000 -W  -fh 0", 
// note ^-------------------------------------------------------------------^^-^^
        saveFilePath + a,
        saveFilePath + b);
```

**Recommended reading:** [string (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/362314fe.aspx)

---

Side note: There's no need for the string concatenation you're doing on the function arguments. Since you're *already* calling `string.Format`, you can have *it* do that:

```
string.Format(
    "-S -E -M -m -e ascii -i {0}{1}.dat -T db1.dbo.table1 -R {2}{3}.reject -t \"|\" -r \r\n -rt value -rv 1000 -W  -fh 0", 
// note ---------------------^^^^^^--------------------------^^^^^^
    saveFilePath,
    a,             // <==
    saveFilePath,
    b);            // <==
```